# Как правильно написать: "на" или "по"?

Tags: синтаксис

*Учебные пособия на изделие техники* или *учебные пособия по изделию техники?*

Comment: По одному только изделию?

Answer (score 1):

Не встречала таких выражений. По-моему, фраза должна звучать как-то так:

*Учебные пособия по технологии создания  изделий техники.*

*Учебные пособия по теме "Производство изделий техники...".*

*Учебные пособия по созданию изделий техники.*

Comment: У меня тоже промелькнула мысль, что автор мог изделие с изготовлением перепутать.

Comment: Это какая-то профессиональная терминология. *Изделия медицинской техники*, *изделия электронной техники* и т.п. — эти термины используются в специальной литературе, в том числе в ГОСТах. Например, микросхема — это изделие электронной техники.

Comment: Изделие техники - это термин, понятно, кто против? А вот пособие на изделие - ни в какие ворота. На изделие (как результат труда) может быть паспорт, к изделию может прилагаться инструкция, руководство, но не учебные пособия. Учебное пособие должно "пособлять" - помогать в изготовлении.

Comment: Людмила, вряд ли речь идёт об изготовлении. Скорее, об эксплуатации и/или устройстве. Гугл находит какие-то сомнительные ссылки на издания типа "Учебное пособие по микроскопу", "Учебное пособие по ЭВМ" и т.п. Но я не рискнул бы рекомендовать такие сокращения вместо полных названий типа "Учебное пособие по устройству...". Хотя не исключаю, что разные ВУЗы могут тиражировать самиздатом методички с сокращёнными названиями. Можно ли счесть эти названия грамотными или хотя бы отнести к профессиональному жаргону? Не думаю.

Comment: Я тоже. "Учебное пособие по ЭВМ" может быть только разговорным вариантом в бытовой ситуации. Например: "Дай мне пособие по ЭВМ", но никак не название пособия.